# Fail to launch Django project on localhost

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, pycharm

I tried to open this project from GitHub https://github.com/konradgalczynski07/vinciu

I used `Pycharm` to open the whole coding file .

[image]

When I run the web app with localhost , it fails and show the errors below. How should I configure this `Django` project and launch on localhost ?

```
>Watching for file changes with StatReloader
>     Performing system checks...
>     
>     System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>     Exception in thread django-main-thread:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 220, in ensure_connection
>         self.connect()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 197, in connect
>         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py",
> line 185, in get_new_connection
>         connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py",
> line 126, in connect
>         conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>     psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>     could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>     
>     
>     The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>     
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py",
> line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>         self.run()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py",
> line 870, in run
>         self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
> line 53, in wrapper
>         fn(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
> line 120, in inner_run
>         self.check_migrations()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 458, in check_migrations
>         executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 18, in __init__
>         self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
> line 49, in __init__
>         self.build_graph()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
> line 212, in build_graph
>         self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
> line 76, in applied_migrations
>         if self.has_table():
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
> line 56, in has_table
>         return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 260, in cursor
>         return self._cursor()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 236, in _cursor
>         self.ensure_connection()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 220, in ensure_connection
>         self.connect()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
> line 90, in __exit__
>         raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 220, in ensure_connection
>         self.connect()
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
> line 197, in connect
>         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py",
> line 185, in get_new_connection
>         connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py",
> line 126, in connect
>         conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>     django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>     could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be stemming from an issue in the database configuration. After looking at the settings.py file in that repository, I noticed that the current configuration is trying to use a postgres server on the localhost. However, it appears that you do not have a postgres server running with those settings, so django fails to connect to that database and throws an error. I can recommend using the sqlite option from the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

After you confirm the database settings are like that in the documentation, use manage.py to rerun your migrations and create all the tables needed in the sqlite database.

Using this sqlite database will be good for development and testing, however once you are ready for a production environment, you will want to switch back to a postgresql or other type of server-based database.

Comment: After I change back to sqlite Db setting , should I do the ``python manage.py makemigrations``& ``python manage.py migrate`` on console? Thanks

Comment: The migrations are more than likely already made, but you will definitely need to at minimum run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: What is the disadvantages if I host the server with sqlite db?